# cmake add_library at a custom location

Tags: cmake

I need to build a library that is to be placed at a custom location stored in the variable CUSTOM_OUTDIR. Currently, I am using the following code to make sure that the library is copied to its proper location.

```
ADD_LIBRARY(example MODULE example.c)

GET_TARGET_PROPERTY(FILEPATH example LOCATION)
ADD_CUSTOM_COMMAND(
    TARGET example POST_BUILD 
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} 
    ARGS -E copy ${FILEPATH} ${CUSTOM_OUTDIR}
)
```

However, this is not a good solution as the copying is done post_build, and I end up with two copies of the library. Is there a way to setup CMAKE_BINARY_DIR just for the `example` library so that only one copy of it is kept in the proper location?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The command

```
set_target_properties(example PROPERTIES 
  LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CUSTOM_OUTDIR}"
)
```

should do what you want.  I'm not in front of a devel machine right now, checking later.